# Debian computer: usr part corrupt

Tags: debian, system-recovery

I have a Debian-Windows dualbooted machine. I've split up all areas into separate parts, eg. `boot`, `var`, `tmp`, etc... are all partitions. Now I can't boot Linux because the `usr` partition is giving I/O errors. Is there any way to recover everything? Or should I copy the `usr` partition off another system I have and hope for the best? Or should I reinstall everything?

Comment: If it is a single disk, split into multiple partitions and you are getting I/O errors from /usr, then the chances are you will get I/O errors from other parts of the disk as well. The disk itself doesn't have the concept of partitions, only blocks. Put it another way, your disk is probably dying and you should get any data that you care about off that disk **now**. Use the disk as little as possible until you have done this, in particular don't bother trying to reinstall anything or repair anything until you have the data saved.

Answer (score 1):

- to be on the really safe side (maybe do all from a live CD/USB stick) use `dd` to save the partition as image somewhere
- use `fsck` to to try to repair the filesystem
- if still something seems broken:
- make a backup of your personal data and the system settings in /etc (and more, depending on your installation, e.g. /var/lib/mysql /usr/local/ etc.)
- get package installation state (out of /var/lib/dpkg/status if `dpkg --get-selections` still not working)
- reinstall based on saved package states